# .MBTiles from mapbox studio

Tags: mapbox

Good day all.

I am a bit Interested in mapbox and your maps. Going thru your site I also realize that calls to the app helps you with revenue. THis is all well and good for doing an app to find the nearest coffee shop. However I am working on an application where Internet connectivity is not promised and in this case a .MBTile file would be perfect for me. I have not been able to export my maps I have created into a .MBTile even though that was directly mentioned in mapbox documentation. I would love some assistance in locating this feature or do I need a paid account to do so.

Ps I am aware this can be done with tilemil but I cannot get the maps I created from Mapkit into tilemil to do so.
Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "maps created from MapKit"? Depending on format, there are different approaches to possibly getting that into TileMill so that you can generate an MBTiles file.

Comment: I meant Mapbox,  sorry I keep saying mapkit because thats what's available in IOS. However I was informed on how to get the .MBTiles from Mapbox, however it's still not. Allowing me to design my map THEN export it as a .mbtile. All I al allowed to do is export a shapefile or a style. which isnnt  helpful at all

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able export .mbtiles you would have to design your map in TileMill. From there you would be able to export them into the format that you want. This would produce raster tiles rather than vector tiles however. https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/